# Multi-Target Regression/Interpolations

Tags: statistics, regression, prediction, data-science

Looking for some advice on the problem I have in front of me.

I have a data set of movies watched by users. For some of the users, we know that they watched the movie, and what their rating is for that movie. For many others we know they watched the movie, but don't know their rating of that movie.

I am looking to find a way to apply a predicted or perhaps interpolated rating to those users movies they watched based on the larger dataset that has movies ratings. I am trying to find out what the best course of action around this would be. I have 1.5m users and 20K movies; however only 10% of those movies are rated by about 85% of users.

My approach is thus looking at cosine similarity and interpolating the rating based on the neighbor; and if the nearest neighbor doesnt have a value for a specific movie, go to the next nearest until all the movies have a rating. The other approach is looking at NNMF to apply ratings, and having 2*features-- one binary representation of the movies, the other the rating. So when I look to "predict" for a user, Ill input their binary movie values and it will return their ratings.

My questions are: Does the NNMF approach make sense? I have never used NNMF in that way. Also, are there any other models you think make sense? I am wondering if their is more of a prediction algorithm that can be employed rather than an interpolation.

Comment: You are dealing with missing data. This will always be dependent on context and domain. In this case, notice that a user who watched something and didn't bother to rate it most likely didn't love nor hate it - I'd fill the missing ratings with the median value. Also, I think you should post this at Cross-Valided with the ['data-imputation' tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-imputation).